# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI 'xxx' because access was denied

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, self-hosting

I've a unit test that work on some computers and fails on other. It does starts one of our component, which have a self-hosted WCF Service.

When it tries to start I get this exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI 'net.tcp://0.0.0.0:55000/VF1/IAccessRightsService' because access was denied.  Verify that the current user is granted access in the appropriate allowAccounts section of SMSvcHost.exe.config.'

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.ReadEndpoint(String sharedMemoryName, String& listenerEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.HandleServiceStart(Boolean isReconnecting)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.Open(Boolean isReconnecting)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.StartListen(Boolean isReconnecting)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedTcpTransportManager.OnOpenInternal(Int32 queueId, Guid token)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListenerBase`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
```

I've seen some similar questions: [WCF error with net.tcp "The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI because access was denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576646/wcf-error-with-net-tcp-the-service-endpoint-failed-to-listen-on-the-uri-because)

But in my case, everything is configured in code, and I cannot find any way to set those "allowed account through code.

Here is how the TCP Binding is configured:

```
public ServiceBinding BuildBinding(String instanceName, string serviceName, bool isFastFailing)
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int64.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, isFastFailing ? TIMEOUT_FOR_FAST_FAILING_SERVICE : TIMEOUT_FOR_NORMAL_SERVICE);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = WcfOperationsConstants.INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT;
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            binding.PortSharingEnabled = true;

            Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(URI_FORMAT, m_ip, m_port, instanceName, serviceName));
            return new ServiceBinding(uri, binding);
        }
```

(then, they are just added endpoint of the `ServiceHost`.

So, how to configure this in code? Or do you have any other idea of what could be the issue?
Why is it working on some computers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

1.Download the [PsGetSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psgetsid). After the download is complete, enter the folder of this tool from cmd and execute the following command to get the sid of the current user.
[image]

2.Open SMSvcHost.exe.config(This file is usually in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ v4.5 ), add your sid into the configuration file. You can refer to this link to add sid: [Configuring the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-the-net-tcp-port-sharing-service)